# SSH keys that can be used only in one machine

Tags: ssh, git, key-authentication, aws, ssh-keygen

My requirement is simple. I have generated a SSH key-pair (Public and Private) on a server say **"A"**. Now I have uploaded my Public SSH key in AWS IAM and have generated a SSH key ID to connect to a CodeCommit Repository via SSH. In server "A" after updating the `".ssh/config"` with the values of SSH-Key ID and path to the private key file I should be able to connect to the repository successfully and I was also able to do this. Now my requirement is when I try to connect to repository from another server say **"B"** (Private key has been trasnfered to the server and the `.ssh/config` file also update as same as in server "A") I should not be able to connnect i.e, the key pair should work only in the server it is generated and not allow connection from any other server. Is this possible? I was not able to find anything solid after googling.

Comment: @drewbenn Just a security measure. Even if one of my developers with access to the repository makes his key public, no one else should be able to access the repo

Answer (score 2):

You can, if the remote uses the usual `authorized_keys` files.

The [`sshd(8)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) describes the `authorized_keys` file format. There are a number of options that can be used in the file, one of them is this:

> `from="pattern-list"`
>
> Specifies that in addition to public key authentication, either  the
>   canonical name of the remote host or its IP address must be  present
>   in the comma-separated list of patterns.  See PATTERNS  in
>   [`ssh_config(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#PATTERNS) for more information on patterns.

So, a line like this would only allow access from `hosta.example.org`:

```
from="hosta.example.org" ssh-rsa AAAA...== user@example.org
```

Though I'm not sure why you wouldn't just create distinct keys for the two client hosts A and B. That would make it very easy to control which host has access where — the keys would be tied to the hosts.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong. From my understanding I have to add this "from=....." in front of the private key's content present in ".ssh/authorized_keys"

Comment: @vishal.k, yes, at the start of the line, before the type (`ssh-rsa`, `ssh-ed25519`, `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` or what have you).

Comment: @vishal.k Just a small correction: `authorized_keys` contains the *public* keys, *not* the private keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as you added the private key to server's B ssh config.
However, you can restrict access to the A server by other means, e.g. firewall rule allowing ssh connection only from one IP.

Comment: Note that there is no need to add the file to the config if it is placed in the correct directory  (`~/.ssh`)

Comment: By config I meant proper directory.

Comment: Guess you guys should check out the below answer from ilkkachu